# How to use enum-like javascript-class that assigns its values without constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, enums, constructor

I have this class, which is supposed to represent an enum:

```
export default class ChangeStatusEnum {
    
        "added" = "added";

        "deleted" = "deleted";

        "edited" = "edited";

        "unedited" = "unedited";

    static constructFromObject(object) {
        return object;
    }
}
```

It is generated in the pipeline by openapi-generator<sup>1</sup> so changing it is not an option. This is not a question on best practices for defining enums in vanilla-js or typescript, this question is about how to use this class.

I do not understand the syntax of assigning to a string, I do not know where these four strings are accessible.

Here are a few things that I have tried (in a jenkins-test so they can be run easily):

```
test("access", () => {
    console.log(ChangeStatusEnum) // prints [class ChangeStatusEnum]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ChangeStatusEnum)) // prints undefined
    console.log(
        ChangeStatusEnum.constructFromObject("deleted") === "deleted"
    ) // prints true
    console.log(
        ChangeStatusEnum.constructFromObject("nonexisting") === "nonexisting"
    ) // also prints true, which means this syntax has no value over just using strings instead of enums
    console.log(ChangeStatusEnum["added"]) // prints undefined
    console.log(ChangeStatusEnum.added) // prints undefined
})
```

The least I expect from a datastructure that calls itself "enum" is that I can construct and compare values of it without fear of silently constructing non-existing values. Iterating over all values of an enum would also be nice, but is not strictly necessary.
I suppose there is a way to do that with this datastructure that I just do not know of due to lack of knowledge of advanced javascript-constructs.

<sup>1</sup> The tool is openapi-generator-cli in version 2.5.1 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli with openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 6.0.0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-maven-plugin
Since this is somewhat mature tooling I expect their enum-solution to be usable, this is why I ask this question as a js-question and not as an openapi-question.

Comment: `added` etc are instance properties ... so `new ChangeStatusEnum()["added"]` will be `"added"` or make "added" etc `static` as well ... then of course, that "class" is pointless as a class, you can just make an Object that does all that

Comment: sorry, didn't read that you can't change the code for that class - so, yeah, those are instance properties so you have to instantiate an instance `new ChangeStatusEnum()` to access those

Comment: @JaromandaX that works. Do you want to turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most elegant way to use it is to create an instance of it and use it as a constant. The 'constructFromObject'-function is not needed for this. So just put this below the imports:

```
const changeStatusEnum = new ChangeStatusEnum();
```

Afterwards, the members can be accessed using normal dot notation:

```
changeStatusEnum.added // evaluates to the string "added"
```